# Properly handling rotation of camera (in TextureView)

Tags: android, android-camera

I try to use a Camera inside my app and I have a problem with proper handling of configuration changes. I know the proper way of handling configuration changes in a typical `Activity` (onSaveInstanceState etc...), but it's not the case here.

Think of my Activity as a fullscreen camera preview with an overlay shutter button and a frame which will be used to crop the image

**What I'm trying to achieve** (preview of a stock HTC Sense camera): http://youtu.be/uzfUJUNHY68

That is: the camera preview which is on `TextureView` should not be recreated on rotation, but the Activity should be orientation-aware, to position elements.

I'm pretty sure I don't want the `Activity` to be recreated on rotation. So I tried the `android:configChanges` approach. The problem is that `onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged()` is still called and the camera preview is rotated and the whole experience is not smooth (the preview lags for a moment and gets "recreated" or something).

I tried locking my Activity to landscape via `android:screenOrientation="landscape"`, but this way `onConfigurationChanged()` is not called and I don't know how to position other views like in the video above. I guess I could listen to some accelerator events, **but I'm pretty sure there is a better way. Is there?**

Comment: A while back I have played with the source code of the stock camera (pre sdk 11), to see how they achieved that behavior for myself. I don't fully remember how they did this, but they handle the orientation change manually and rotate the image in the imageviews. Might be worth a look because it was implemented in a very simple way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Android camera source](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_camera/blob/master/src/com/android/camera/CameraActivity.java).

Lock activity rotation. On method `onOrientationChanged` of `MyOrientationEventListener` you can rotate, change positions of views etc. I think it's a best way.

Comment: In ICS Camera you can find simple code for smooth rotate widgets (in the same listener). https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_camera/blob/ics-mr1-release/src/com/android/camera/Camera.java

Comment: But still, the status bar will be displayed always with portrait mode (on top of the device) and not handled by the rotation.

Answer (score -1):

Try with this option.

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: I already tried and wrote it in my question: "I'm pretty sure I don't want the Activity to be recreated on rotation. So I tried the android:configChanges approach."